# Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated

Tags: javascript, ajax, java-ee, jsf

Есть ошибка, которая все ломает. После того, как она выдалась, все остальные скрипты отпадают.  Как это исправить? Вот код.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>


    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:link outcome="create" value="Insert a new diver"></h:link>

        <h:form  id="myForm">
                <p:dataTable   value="#{diverController.lst}" var="d"  scrollable="true" scrollHeight="500" style="width:800px;margin-left: auto;">
                <p:column headerText="Id" >
                    #{d.id}
                </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Name" >
                    #{d.name}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Num">
                    #{d.num}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Status">
                   #{d.status}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Lat">
                   #{d.lat}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Lot">
                   #{d.lot}
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Action">
                    <h:commandLink value ="Remove"
                                   action="#{diverController.remove(d)}"
                                   onclick="return confirm('Are you Sure')"></h:commandLink>||
                  <h:commandLink value="Edit"
                       action="#{diverController.edit(d)}"></h:commandLink>

                </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Check"  >
                        <p:commandButton id="mButn" class="Bzazaza" ></p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            <p:poll update="myForm" interval="10" ></p:poll>
            </h:form>

   <h:outputScript library="js" name="example.js"></h:outputScript>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

А вот ошибка

```
jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=5.0:25 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
```

Comment: Покажите кусок кода из `jquery.js?ln=primefaces&v=5.0`... возможно 25 это строка.

Comment: @nick_n_a ну кусок из jquery.js это будет наверное код отправки xhr, надо пройтись по стеку, найти момент отправки запроса и смотреть уже там.

Comment: btw кажется синхронные xhr должны выдавать warning, но не ошибку. Но точно не уверен)

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму дА это предупреждение не ошибка )

Comment: а можно её оставить?)

Comment: или она сильно скажется на моем приложении?

Comment: Да, это warning что в XMLHttpRequest  что-то устарело. Может даже синхронные запросы. Вам тогда нужно обновить jquery наверно...

Comment: А какие способы обновия jquery есть?

Comment: @nick_n_a ну какой обновить jquery, чушь не несите плз) надо убрать флаг "этот запрос - синхронный" в месте где посылатеся запрос. Ну и да, синхронный xhr - deprecated о чем прямым текстом написано.

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму а где имеено в приведенном коде нужно снять/поставить отметку что б запрос стал асинхронным - тогда это  и есть ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Лан мужики давайте не спорить)Я протестил и покапался на англо язычных ресурсах .Причина сего дела  scrollable="true" как бы он уже использует потоки так  далее .Нашел решение вот такое заменил таблицу от прайм face на просто h<:datable>  вроде все заработало .Но веже хотелось с primfaces сделать ....

Comment: @nick_n_a, нет. Во-первых потому что это warning код автора ломается не из-за этого. Во вторых видимо эти данные отправляются синхронно потому что форма, поэтому флажком видимо отделаться не удастся) Но точно сказать не могу, я jsf не знаю и тут бы отладиться